# change html form field height on page load

Tags: html, css, forms

I have the below code from chrome inspect

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: _onChange" class="axios-form-multi-select dijitMultiSelect" tabindex="0" id="uniqName_4_22" widgetid="uniqName_4_22" data-auto-test-id="webCustomPropertyValue(DOCUMENT TYPE 12)" aria-labelledby="uniqName_38_19_labelNode uniqName_38_19_descriptionNode" style="height: 76px; width: 323px;"></select>
```

Iam trying to change this field height by adding a css code in the page header because i can not access the source css code

Below is what i tried, but didn't work, Is this possible? Any workarounds?

```css
.axios-form-multi-select {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange: _onChange" class="axios-form-multi-select dijitMultiSelect" tabindex="0" id="uniqName_4_22" widgetid="uniqName_4_22" data-auto-test-id="webCustomPropertyValue(DOCUMENT TYPE 12)"
  aria-labelledby="uniqName_38_19_labelNode uniqName_38_19_descriptionNode" style="height: 76px; width: 323px;"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to the `inline-styles` applied to the `selector` element:
`style="height: 76px; width: 323px;"`.

Inline styles have higher precedence than *class-based styles*. Removing this will do the job.